# Quick question about algebras

Tags: measure-theory

One of the requirements for an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is that $\Omega$$\in$$\mathcal{A}$. But does $\Omega$ have to be it's own element in $\mathcal{A}$ or is it enough to let $\mathcal{A}$ consist of sets whose union is equal to $\Omega$?

Example: 
If $\Omega$={1,2,3}, is $\mathcal{A}$={{1},{2,3}} an algebra? Seeing as {1}$\cup${2,3}=$\Omega$

Comment: I don't know the precise definition of an algebra of sets, but the question sounds like "This is the definition. But what about this thing that doesn't satisfy the definition? Does it satisfy the definition?"

Answer (score 1):

If for $\mathcal{A}$ to be an algebra on a set $\Omega$ you need $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$, then a subset $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ without $\Omega \in A$ is not an algebra.

I'm interpreting 'algebra' to mean a set containing $\Omega$ and closed under complements and finite unions of its elements. If $\mathcal{A} = \{ \{1\}, \{2,3\} \}$ then $\mathcal{A}$ is not an algebra on $\{1, 2, 3\}$. It fails on two counts: first since $\{ 1, 2, 3 \} \not \in \mathcal{A}$, and second since $\{ 1 \} \cup \{ 2, 3 \} \not \in \mathcal{A}$ so it is not closed under finite unions.